# Customize local busy indicator

Tags: sapui5

```js
sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.getId()).setBusy(true);
```

In CSS:

```css
.sapUiLocalBusyIndicator {
    background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1) !important;
}
```

I have made the local busy indicator opaque for one of the screens but the problem is that it applies to all the screens of my application while I only need it for the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refine the CSS rule to only apply to your Control / View by adding a class to both:

JS:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.getId()).setBusy(true).addStyleClass("opaqueBusyIndicator");
```

(Ideally you add the class on creation or definition.)

CSS:

```css
.opaqueBusyIndicator .sapUiLocalBusyIndicator {
    background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
}
```

(With both classes, you also don't necessarily need `!important`.)

Comment: thanks for the info I was not sure if we can add styleClass to busy indicators.

Comment: The class is not actually added to the busy indicator, but the control that is set to busy. (`setBusy()` returns `this` i.e. the Control)